# Rest api response error json

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, ajax, einstein-analytics, ajax-toolkit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXguZ.jpg)I am connecting wave rest api using Ajax toolkit.I am getting error response like the below image if I pass the SAQL to the `Wave REST API`:[image]

[image]

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true">
<script src="/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function ctrlwave(){ 
         sforce.connection.init('{!$API.Session_ID}','https://xxxxxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/wave/query');
         var envelope = "{query:\"q = load \"xxxxx\";\nq = group q by 'Name';\nq = foreach q generate 'Name' as 'Name', count() as 'count';\nq = order q by 'Name' asc;\nq = limit q 2;\"}";
         sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
                url : "https://key--xxxxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/wave/query",
                requestHeaders: {"Authorization":"Bearer "+'{!$API.Session_ID}',"Content-Type":"application/json",}, 
                requestData: envelope,
                method: "POST",
                onSuccess : function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                   },
              onFailure : function(response) {
              alert("Failed" + response)
          }
   });
     }        
  </script>
<apex:form >
<div>Wave TOOL</div>
<apex:commandButton onclick="ctrlwave();" value="waveRet" id="theButton"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this payload:

```
{query: "..."}
```

You need to change it to:

```
{"query": "..."}
```

Which, since you have it wrapped in double quotes, is:

```
"{\"query\": \"...\"}"
```

---

I believe you also need to change `load \"xxxxx\"` to `load 'xxxxx'`, but I cannot confirm.

Comment: Hi I have modified as you said .But Now also I am getting errors.First I tried by changing the payload error1 came check the question section for screenshot.Later I Modified the dataset name from \" to '.Where I getting error error2 refer the question for screenshot

Comment: First of all, you should paste in your error message text, instead of screenshots of the error. Second of all, the format of this forum makes continuous edits of a question not very useful. It would be better to ask a new question and link to this one for context if necessary.